# Handle thousands of sql inserts for realtime chat application using nodejs and postgresSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, socket.io

I have a chat application that is built using websockets, NodeJS and postgreSQL. On the client side the user sends the message and socket io server on nodejs receives the event, saves the result in postgreql database using `pg` npm package and notifies all the connected sockets with new message.

It all works fine until the nodejs socket server starts to receive very large number of messages in small time. For example, 1000 new messages sent from different client browsers to web socket server that needs to insert that into database and then send the newly sent message to recipients.

I want to know how to speed this up?
I am already using connecting pooling on postgresql database server but still insert statements take lot of time when executed in very small amount of time.

Do I need to use some queuing system on server? If so what are options?

Here is may current code snippet:

Client Side:

```
socket.emit('message', {message: 'Hi', user_id: 125, room_id: 100});
```

Here is my server side code (node.js+socket.io library)

```
    socket.on('message', function(data){
    
     var query = connection.query(new pg.Query("INSERT INTO message(room_id, user_id,message,sent_datetime) values($1, $2,$3,$4
) RETURNING conversation_message_id", [data.room_id, data.user_id, data.message, new Date()));
            query.on('end', function (result) {
                 io.sockets.in(data.room_id).emit('new_message', result);
            });
    });
```

On client side again:

```
socket.on('new_message', function(newMessage){

 //Render logic in message window
});
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and set `synchronous_commit = off`.

Comment: How big is the pool?  How multi-threaded is the app server?  How much time is a "lot of time"?

Comment: Also, what are you creating a new pg.client with each insert? I could be mistaken here but that may be instantiating a new connection to the DB each request, your connection.query already contains the connection, so you should be able to just do connection.query('quersy statement).  Postgres is fairly quick, so one question is what number of writes are you seeing per second, and as stated what is slow? Also as mentioned, how many instances are you running, this could also be the eventloop slowing down because its not able to handle the request, in that case you will need to add more servers.

Comment: @proxim0 I am reusing the connection, that logic is not shown here. 
On top of that I am also using pgbouncer for connection pooling. 
I have not calculated number of writes per second but when about 100 messages per second are sent to server then it slows down. Primarily due to database inserts.